# How can I make a frame as a border that just shows as a plain 1px line?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a frame like this to put an outline around a label.

But I have two problems with the way it looks

```
    <Frame Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" OutlineColor="Black">
      <Label  x:Name="faveIconLabel" Style="{StaticResource mediumIcon}" Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Fill" FontFamily="FontAwesome" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    </Frame>
```

- The border is very wide and all I really want is a border of 1px
- The label text is hidden and I can't see it.

Can anyone give me advice on how to solve these two problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin Form's `Frame` class sets the default padding to 20, so you will have to set it to 0 or so to solve the extra space issue. Unfortunately you can't edit the border width without using a custom renderer.

Comment: Oh the border width is very important to me.  Is there any other way to do this using something other than a frame where I can get border radius?